# Register controller in another assembly in ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to make a shared library for a .NET MVC Core 1.1 app that contains a controller that needs to be registered in the host MVC app.

I've found some examples of this for earlier versions of .NET Core but none of them seem to work in the current release.

This was the approach that looked most promising:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(OtherAssembly.Controller).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    .AddControllersAsServices();
```

I have not altered the standard routes so they still look like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I have a controller called SimpleController in my other assembly and it has an index action.

I'm trying the url

/simple

but I'm getting a 404. Has something changed, or am I missing something. And is there a way in .NET Core to debug routes.

**Update:** I was trying to do this in a .NET Standard Class Library. As soon as I switched to using a .NET Core Class library all worked fine and as expected, without any extra setup and I was able to remove the AddControllersAsServices part.

I guess there was no strong reason, other than experimentation why I was using .NET Standard class library, but I'd still like to know why it doesn't seem like you can.

Comment: Controllers from another assemblies are registered in entry web app by default (at least in Core 1.1). Maybe you have a routing issue?

Comment: I've added some more details in case the issue is something other than the assembly.

Comment: Could you post your external controller? Which project type is used to contain it?

Comment: I didn't think the project type would affect this as long as it all compiled, but looks like that was the issue. Changed the question slightly to reflect this.