# Sharing Default MVC controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

At the moment I am building a lot of small API's at work. Many of these projects shares some basic controllers logic. Is there some way to add them to a nuget package and just use them during startup?
Eg. like adding Mvc:

```
IApplicationBuilder app;    
....    

app.UseMvc;
app.UseBasicApiVersionController();
```

The idea is we have version endpoint in all our microservices.
Eg:
http://url/version
returns { "version": "1.0.0" }
How would I make this into a nuget package?
So all developers only have to add 1 line of code to add this endpoint to their micro service? We are using dotnet core.
Don't help to create the nuget package it self :)

My guess for getting started is something similar to this:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseBasicApiVersionController(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
      if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("app");

      ..... // What should I do?

      return app;
    }
```

*Edit:
If you add a controller to nuget package project it will be automatic detected. But that is not the functionality I want.
I might have 10 services that need that controller. While having 1-2 services that only want's the other version control logic. Eg. Customer facing App's shouldn't have a "/version" endpoint.
That's why I want during startup to use app.UseBasicApiVersionController();

Comment: As an alternative approach: what about creating a default project template with your default controllers. Or just a project. You then could just clone the repo and could start with everything you need. You could even fork/ branch out that project to create different starting points for different kinds of microservices.

Comment: @Marco > Had thought about it. But if we in the future change the logic for how the version endpoint works, we would have to go into all our projects and fix it.    
Eg. Right now we only need Version number.    
But later we might need label: Aplha / beta / release.    
It would be nice just having a nuget package to update rather than opening all legacy projects and add the new logic for the default controller.

Comment: You could also use dependency injection. You could provide an url formatter class of some sorts that accepts all the dynamic data that you need to construct a valid client url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just for version you could add a shared extension or a piece of middleware that return version.

```
public class VersionMiddleware: OwinMiddleware
{
    private static readonly PathString Path = new PathString("/version");
    private OwinMiddleware Next;

    public VersionMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        if (!context.Request.Path.Equals(Path))
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        var version = Assembly.[HowToGetYourVersionAsAnObject]

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData));
    }
}
```

Comment: The Idea is it has to be dynamic and used for other stuff than just version.
Like described in comment.
If I in the future would like to return Version + Label. Or an entire Razor view.

Comment: Returning a razor view may be a different capability. The others are just a number of middleware components.

Comment: But you are correct. It is not as versatile as controllers. The question is whether or not it is a requirement or designing for some potential requirement of the future.

Comment: Aren't the controllers in the nuget package registered automatically? The should according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/44098200

Comment: > They are. But I only want them registered if I call the function.